# generator-angular module is not creating a new project

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am new to yeoman set of tools. I run following commands in Ubuntu 12

```
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-webapp
$ yo webapp
```

I am able to create a web app project. After that I tried to create an angular project. First I run a command

```
$ npm install -g generator-angular
```

And no error is displayed with installation of this generator.

When I run the command

```
$ yo angular
```

I get the error:

```
Error angular
You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 2 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

How to resolve this? When I run the command

```
 $ ls $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules
```

output is:

```
bower  generator-angular  generator-karma  generator-mocha  generator-webapp  grunt-cli  yo
```

The same problem occurred when I use to install generator-backbone using

```
$ npm install -g generator-backbone
```

It installs the package successfully and when I run the command in an empty folder

```
$ yo backbone
```

It's giving the output

```
Error backbone 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name backbone installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 2 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

When I run the command

```
$ npm config get prefix
```

It's giving me the output

```
/home/ritesh/npm
```

Perhaps I am doing some mistake in this path. Can any one tell how to resolve it?

Comment: What do you get if you run just `yo`?

Comment: On Ubuntu `prefix` should be set to `/usr`. There must be sth setting it incorrectly for you. Perhaps `~/.npmrc` file ?

Comment: thanks ur solution worked i changed prefix to /usr and now its works like a charm.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly this problem but my prefix is `/usr/local/share/npm` which looks correct.

Comment: for my system is usr/local/lib/npm

Answer (score 6):

`NODE_PATH` is probably not configured properly. In which case, just add the NPM prefix to the `NODE_PATH`. If you run `yo doctor`, the output is likely to be:

```
[Yeoman Doctor] Uh oh, I found potential errors on your machine
---------------

[Error] NPM root value is not in your NODE_PATH
  [info]
    NODE_PATH = /usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
    NPM root  = /home/eliranm/npm/lib/node_modules

  [Fix] Append the NPM root value to your NODE_PATH variable
    Add this line to your .bashrc
      export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/eliranm/npm/lib/node_modules
    Or run this command
      echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/eliranm/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

So, in order to solve this, just follow the doctor's orders. If you prefer to change the `.profile` configuration rather the bash's, just execute this:

```bash
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/eliranm/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.profile && source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

ISSUE: 'yo doctor' can find no errors on Windows 10. Updating yeoman didn't fix.
FIX: May be a permission problem. I opened command prompt as Admin , run yo xxxx, it worked.